# MVVM, ViewModelLocator, dynamically show View with ViewModel based on property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ivalueconverter, viewmodellocator

[image]I have a design question. Please look at the attached image to get an idea of the app design.
Basicaly I just need help in finding the correct approach here.

I have a View and ViewModel that holds an TileUserControl.
It takes a collection of tiles, and displays them in the defined size, color, order and so one. It is also capable of grouping the tales in groups, and allowing the user to add and remove Tiles.

The Tile object look like this.

```
    public class Tile
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string View { get; set; }
        public List<string> Views { get; set; }
        public string TileSize { get; set; }

    }
```

So far all good. Everything works fine.

All tiles have content. I want to set the content to the View and the ViewModel corresponding to the View string on the Tile Object.

I am using MVVM Light, but may also use Caliburn Mico.
The tiles Control is DevExpress TileLayoutControl for WPF.

[DevExpress TileLayoutControl doc](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfLayoutControlTileLayoutControltopic)

EDIT: Updated With MainTilesView XAML

```
    <Grid>

        <dxlc:TileLayoutControl Padding="60,41,0,0"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}" 
                                ScrollBars="None" 
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                AllowGroupHeaderEditing="False" 
                                AllowMaximizedElementMoving="True" Background="{x:Null}">

            <dxlc:TileLayoutControl.GroupHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="dxlc:TileGroupHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segeo UI"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
                </Style>
            </dxlc:TileLayoutControl.GroupHeaderStyle>

            <dxlc:TileLayoutControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <dxlc:Tile Header="{Binding Header}" 
                               Size="{Binding TileSize}" 
                               dxlc:TileLayoutControl.GroupHeader="{Binding GroupHeader}" 
                               Tag="{Binding ID}"  
                               dxlc:FlowLayoutControl.IsFlowBreak="{Binding IsNewGroup}" 
                               Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
                    </dxlc:Tile>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxlc:TileLayoutControl.ItemTemplate>

            <dxlc:TileLayoutControl.Resources>
                <conv:IsUserControlConverter x:Key="IsUserControlConverter"/>
                <conv:StringToTileConverter x:Key="StringToTileConverter"/>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxlc:Tile}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}" Value="ExtraSmall">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="ExtraSmall"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}" Value="1x1">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="ExtraSmall"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}" Value="1x1">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="Small"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="150"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}"  Value="1x2">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="Large"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}"  Value="2x1">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="ExtraLarge"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="310"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}"  Value="2x2">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="ExtraLarge"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}"  Value="2x3">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="ExtraLarge"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="310"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="470"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}"  Value="3x2">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="ExtraLarge"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="470"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="310"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}"  Value="3x3">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="ExtraLarge"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="470"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="470"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}"  Value="4x2">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="ExtraLarge"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="630"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="310"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}"  Value="4x3">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="ExtraLarge"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="630"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="470"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}"  Value="4x4">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="ExtraLarge"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="630"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="630"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TileSize}"  Value="Single_1x1">
                            <Setter Property="Size" Value="Large"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="150"/>
                        </DataTrigger>



                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=View,Converter={StaticResource IsUserControlConverter}}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=View, Converter={StaticResource StringToTileConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>                                        
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </dxlc:TileLayoutControl.Resources>

        </dxlc:TileLayoutControl>
    </Grid>
```

My issue is how to get the UserControl from Tile.View loaded into the Tile content.
I have tride above with DataTrigger and DataTemplate.

The StringToTileConverter just Returns the name of the ViewModel.

Currently using Caliburn Micro, and my binding workes fine outside of the template part, but I can't get them to work with the DataTemplate.

Also all this code is not very clean, so therefor I ask if anyone have a more clean way to do it.

Comment: Nice drawing :) Have you tried anything? Could you post what you got so far or are you asking us to do this for you? :)

Comment: Sorry but I think that I don't understand wich is exactly the question... Are you asking for an advice about the MVVM framework to achieve this design?

Comment: :-) Currently I have everything working in a static way. Meaning that I have defined all tiles and contentcontrols for 30 tiles. But I would like to make it possible for the user to select what tiles he/she need. Therefor I introdused the Tile Object and BindableCollection<Tile> Collection. But I am not able to "wire" things back up again.

Comment: Make sure you check out the DataTemplateSelector. You can create whatever logic you need to return the proper view for each Tile object.

Comment: What do you mean by "My issue is how to get the UserControl from Tile.View loaded into the Tile content." ??? can you separate this Issue and explain exactly what are you trying to do? what tile.view loaded??? what is tile content?? and what is "getting"? get a reference to it? move it to somewhere else? what do you mean?

Comment: Use a convention based approach to locating views (by name for example so TileViewModel expects a TileView to exists in the assembly), bind the ViewModels that have Views on a ContentControl and use a ViewLocator converter to automatically load the appropriate View.
ContentControl Content="{Binding TileViewModel, Converter={StaticResource ViewLocator}"/>

Comment: Wait, why are you trying to "get the user control"? And where are you trying to do this? That suggests to me you're trying to do something you shouldn't actually be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.com/), you can take advantage of its built-in **ViewLocator**. You don't need converters or DataTriggers, as you can define the DataTemplate as follows:

```
  <DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl Width="100" Height="100" cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
  </DataTemplate>
```

You may find this helpful: [Binding ListBox to a collection of screens (widgets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228873/binding-listbox-to-a-collection-of-screens-widgets)

Let me know if you need a more throughout example.